# How do I convert a .jar file to a .ipa file?

Tags: java, cocoa, jar, ipod-touch, ipa

I recently made a simple .jar file called "circle.jar". All it does is draw a green circle to the screen. The code to the file is below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;    
public class CircleDraw extends Frame {
    float x;
    Shape circle = new Ellipse2D.Float(110.0f, 40.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f);
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D ga = (Graphics2D)g;
    ga.setColor(Color.green);
    ga.draw(circle);  
    ga.setPaint(Color.green);
    ga.fill(circle);
}
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Frame frame = new CircleDraw();
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
            System.exit(0);
      }
    });
    frame.setSize(320, 480);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Now, I was wondering if I could somehow convert/compile this to a .ipa file for my iPod touch. I have a 4<sup>th</sup> generation jailbroken iPod touch.
Also, if this is not possible, then I was pondering whether or not I could compile the .java or the .class file to an Objective-C file. I have heard of [XML<sup>VM</sup>](http://xmlvm.org/overview/), but to successfully use it you would need to have the Cocoa Library installed. However, I am using a PC with Windows 7 and  as far as I know, the Cocoa Library is not available for download on a PC. (However, if it is *please* let me know!)
I also realize that the exact code may not be able to compile for the iPod touch, but that doesn't matter. The code was just given as a sample.
*Any* help is *greatly* appreciated!
:)

Comment: Assuming you have all the code (above), wouldn't it be easier to rewrite it in Objective C?

Answer (score 0):

There are some tools for this, but they require you to have a Mac together with a developing licence for 99$.

For example: [Titanium](http://www.appcelerant.com/titanium-developer.html)

You wouldn't need a developer license if your iPhone is jailbreaked though, then you could just add the .ipa to a respitory and then download it from for example Cydia.
You'll still need a Mac, though.

Comment: You don't need a developer license to run/debug an iPhone app locally, only xcode.

Comment: Yes, sorry that I forgot to mention this before, but I do not plan on posting my application in the AppStore. I do not know if this changes the fact that I would need a developer license or not.

Comment: You wouldn't need a developer license if your iPhone is jailbreaked though, then you could just add the .ipa to a respitory and then download it from for example Cydia. You'll still need a Mac, though. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to just write that same code in Objective-C and use the [iOS development toolchain](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/an-absolute-beginners-guide-to-iphone-development) to get it on your iPod Touch.

Comment: Correct, but I don't have a Mac.

Comment: I apologize for glossing over the PC part of your post. There really isn't a good free way to do this that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

Your best platforms for cross-platform development are [listed on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_phone_web_based_application_framework).